# Sqlite: Search Ids in a list and if else in query

Tags: android, sqlite

Here is what I want: Update the table with the Ids from a list of Ids and where conditionally set the column with a value depending on the Id. Sample query. For learning purposes, I would like to know if this query qualifies as valid SQLite query and if it will work as I am expecting:

```
UPDATE  relations_table
SET  is_active =  (CASE WHEN  relation_id = ( relation_id IN ('1', '2', '3'))  THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END)
```

Comment: @forpas Yes, that

Answer (score 0):

Unexpectedly worked(am no SQL expert so kinda *unexpected*):

```
UPDATE relations_table
SET is_active= (CASE WHEN relation_id IN ('0', '1', '7', '8') THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END)
```

Also, the complexity is O(N)

Comment: @forpas : Indeed. I have a list of Ids(strings) to update some entries. I think, I didn't phrase the question properly and that caused the confusion.